# rake failure due to imagemagick

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, imagemagick, rake

I'm seeding a development database (mysql) using `rake db:seed` in Rails 3. The rake task fails, stating,

> Validation failed: Logo /var/folders/.../logo.png is not recognized by the 'identify' command.

When I run `which identify`, I get the expected path `/usr/local/bin/identify`. ImageMagick is indeed installed (via Homebrew), and *appears* to work with png images just fine from the command line.

I even rebuilt the app on another machine, thinking that my environment is borked,  and I got the same error.

Is there a poltergeist in my terminal sessions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running a bundle exec before the rake. In the past this has often solved these sorts of problems for me. It will ensure your rails environment is loaded before running the rake task.

```
bundle exec rake db:seed
```

Hope that helps!

// Addition

Also are you using the Paperclip gem to do this import? I do remember that I needed to ensure the path to ImageMagick was set in my development.rb file to ensure this was picked up.

Eg.

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin"
```